# add WCF Discovery api support to an .net 3.5 app

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

Is it possible to add the WCF Discovery API to a .net 3.5 application.
The target machines have .net 3.5 installed and We don't want to have to install .net 4, is it possible to only add the Discovery API ?
I there another way to implement discovery with the older wcf .net 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31285/WS-Discovery-for-WCF